# Laravel - syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a website which works fine on host, but I'm currently trying to install it on localhost.

I've downloaded everything and configured to work on localhost - Database & URL.

The problem is this error:

> Unhandled Exception
>
> Message:
>
> syntax error, unexpected end of file Location:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\laravel\view.php(386) :
>   eval()'d code on line 118

And I don't know what causes it. Any solutions?

P.S. I've setup in my windows' host file `127.0.0.1 myproject.dev`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is an error within one of your views. If there is a more detailed stack trace it should show you details of a view, although the name will be an `md5()` string so it's a bit hard to find. You might want to delete all compiled Blade views in `storage/views` and let Blade re-compile the views.

If you still get the error then check your views to make sure you have all the proper closing tags, e.g., `@endif` or `@endforeach`

Always double check your views for any syntax errors.

Comment: It looked like I havent had my short tags turned on. :( Everything is ok so far.

Comment: That would do it too! Instead of using short tags you should take a look at Blade. :)

Comment: I think that blade is convertion `@foreach($foo as $bar)` to `<? foreach($foo as $bar): ?>`. Anyways I fixed this. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Consider marking this as the correct answer if it answers your question, otherwise people will assume it's unsolved.

Comment: Ok, but just edit your answer and include the possibility with the short tags. So if someone gets this problem to find it easily. :)

Comment: In my case it was a missing semicolon in the routes file. It's a shame the error message doesn't even mention the file name!

Comment: @dotslash Where did you miss the semicolon?

Comment: @LuigiLopez Too long ago to remember today, but I guess, at the end of the route definition . . .

Answer (score 8):

I've run into this same error and I was able to fix it by adding spaces to the content within an inline if statement. For example:

Experienced error with:

```
@if( BLAH )Output@endif
```

Fixed error with:

```
@if( BLAH ) Output @endif
```

This may not be a problem in all cases and it was certainly difficult to track down but it is just one example that can cause this exact error.

Comment: I had this problem too, and this solved it. This issue seems to have happened because we upgraded to Laravel 4.2; the old code works fine in Laravel 4.1. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184925/unexpected-endforeach-in-blade-template/).

Answer (score 5):

A variation of this problem -- I had a php block, which I'd opened with 
`<?`  as opposed to `<?php` worked fine on LocalHost/MAMP, but gave the above error under Nginx/Ubuntu 16.04/PHP7 (both Laravel)

Comment: That's probably due to disabled short tags in your `php.ini` config. Enabling them is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove a character from view file. for example my character was "," (a comma) before some "@endfor". when i remove those worked!