# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, laravel

I added manually the Admin LTE and put it on my theme-asset folder and I imported it like this on my `app.blade.php`

The stacktrace is showing the end of line of the code. I don't know what's wrong with it. I'm just trying to make it to work and view the admin lte dashboard. Can someone please help me out . I just new to laravel. Hope someone can help me

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://ielev8net.com/theme-assets/images/logo/ielev8net_logo.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://ielev8net.com/theme-assets/images/logo/ielev8net_logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme-assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme-assets/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Morris chart -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/morris.js/morris.css')}}">
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css') }}">
    <!-- Date Picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css') }}">
    <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('theme-assets/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css') }}">
    <!-- END Page Level CSS-->






<!-- jQuery 3 -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
      $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Morris.js charts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/raphael/raphael.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/morris.js/morris.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/dist/js/adminlte.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js') }} " type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="{{ asset('theme-assets/dist/js/demo.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL JS-->
```

Comment: If that's all what you have in your view, you should get a blank page and no errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - syntax error, unexpected end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116212/laravel-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)